# Error when installing juggernaut on rails. juggernaut -g juggernaut.yml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, juggernaut

I followed the instructions for creating a basic juggernaut chat in rails [here](http://slightlycoded.com/blog/the-juggernaut-a-push-server-for-ruby-on-rails) but I get the following error when running `juggernaut -g juggernaut.yml` All the steps before this went smoothly. Any help would be appreciated.

```
MacPro:simplechat fred$ juggernaut -g juggernaut.yml
/Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/maccman-juggernaut-0.5.9/lib/juggernaut/server.rb:128: warning: else without rescue is useless
/Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require': /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/maccman-juggernaut-0.5.9/lib/juggernaut/server.rb:122: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting keyword_then or ',' or ';' or '\n' (SyntaxError)
        when :broadcast: broadcast_command
                        ^
/Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/maccman-juggernaut-0.5.9/lib/juggernaut/server.rb:363: syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/maccman-juggernaut-0.5.9/lib/juggernaut.rb:157:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p180/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:54:in `require'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/gems/maccman-juggernaut-0.5.9/bin/juggernaut:3:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/juggernaut:19:in `load'
    from /Users/fred/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p180/bin/juggernaut:19:in `<main>'
```